# GraphQL Resolver for Interface on same Mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I'm creating a GraphQL server that uses Mongoose and GraphQLInterfaceType. I have a GraphQLInterfaceType of Books and sub types of SchoolBooksType and ColoringBookType. in my Mongoose Schema I specified that both SchoolBooks and ColoringBooks are to be stored in the same books collection

```
const coloringSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,//Interface
  pages: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ColoringBook", coloringSchema , "books");
```

```
const schoolSchema = new Schema({
  title: String, //Interface
  subject: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("SchoolBook", schoolSchema , "books");
```

Here is one of my types

```
const SchoolBookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "SchoolBook",
  interfaces: [BooksInterface],
  isTypeOf: obj => obj instanceof SchoolBook,
  fields: () => ({
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    subject: { type: GraphQLString }
  })
});
```

Here is my query: **But I don't know what to return, if I need to combine the two collections into the same array?**

```
books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(BooksInterface),
      resolve() {
        return SchoolBook.find({})  //<---- What to return?
      }
    }
```

Here is my query:

```
{
  books{
title
    ... on ColoringBook{
      pages

    }

    ... on SchoolBook{
      subject
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use an async resolver, and concat both queries.

```
resolve: async () => {
  const schoolBooks = SchoolBook.find({}).exec()
  const coloringBooks = ColoringBook.find({}).exec()

  const [sbooks, cbooks] = await Promise.all([schoolBooks, coloringBooks])
  return [...sbooks, ...cbooks]
}
```